# Use include which work linear?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I don't understand, I want to use include .js file with IoJS (fork of NodeJS), for example:

```
// in file var.js: 
var variableOne, variableTwo = {}, variable3 = [];

// in file function.js
function test(a, b){return a*b;}

// include module vehicle which use function test(), and my variable
// include module buildind '' '' '' '' ....

// ...
```

But when I do that, I have error because function test doesn't exist, or variable doesn't exist...

How I can do that? 
Thank you

Comment: Are you sure they are included in the right order?

Comment: var colors = require('colors'); var Vehicle = require('./Vehicle'); 
And: Vehicle.js:9 ReferenceError: colors is not defined

Comment: Local variables are not magically becoming available in included modules. Either pass the values to those modules or require all dependencies in the module itself.

Comment: It's not possible to include file.js and their include in order, like that I can include my function and use it in my other include..? You know what I can? Thanks

Comment: As I said, either explicitly pass the values that the module needs to the module, or let the module require those dependencies itself. There is no other (sensible) way.

Comment: Alright. How I can give dependencies to the module?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't provide you with include functionality.
You should either use HTML import

```
<script src="filepath/filename.js"></script>
```

or use some more advanced techniques, like jQuery [getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/).

```
$.getScript( "ajax/test.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
  console.log( data ); // Data returned
  console.log( textStatus ); // Success
  console.log( jqxhr.status ); // 200
  console.log( "Load was performed." );
});
```

Comment: I can't use HTML, I work with IoJS (fork or NodeJS). Sorry I forget to talk about it.

Comment: Please edit your question and mention that. It's quite important =)